# Travis build OpenJDK10 with JavaFx support

Tags: java, javafx, travis-ci, java-10

Since a few days travis does not support the jdk option oraclejdk10 anymore. So I tried to move to openjdk10. The problem is, that I need JavaFX support, and I get various error messages for various tries to get it working:

Try 1:

```
language: java

install: true

script: "cd Aggregation; mvn test -B"

sudo: false
jdk:
    - openjdk10

notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
      - junktogo@web.de
    on_success: change
on_failure: always
```

Travis error:
Multiple packages like javafx.application do not exist

Try 2 (Install the openjfx package):
I added the following section:

```
before_install:
    - sudo apt install -y openjfx
```

Travis error:

```
E: Unable to locate package openjfx
The command "sudo apt install -y openjfx" failed and exited with 100 during.
```

This problem remains even if adding `sudo apt update`.

Try 3:

```
before_install:
    - sudo apt-get build-dep libopenjfx-java
    - sudo apt-get --compile source libopenjfx-java
```

Travis error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libopenjfx-java
The command "sudo apt-get build-dep libopenjfx-java" failed and exited with 100 during.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jan S. suggested including JavaFX using a Maven dependency instead of trying to build it using Travis works just fine.
Add something like the following to your Maven dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Teavis build with OpenJDK 8

```
language: java
dist: bionic
jdk:
  - openjdk8
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update -q
  - sudo apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
  - chmod +x deploy.sh
after_success:
  - ./deploy.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a proper setup of OpenJFX to bring it to work since JavaFX is not included in OpenJDK and also you should upgrade to OpenJDK 11 since Java 10 is EOL (End of Life).

Checkout the official documentation:
https://openjfx.io/

OpenJDK 11:
https://jdk.java.net/11/

Comment: "EOL" stands for?

Comment: I thought it means "end of line". Those abbreviations are confusing.

Comment: That´s exactly what I am trying to do.
How can I either download binaries of openjfx and put it somewhere where it can be found by travis or how can I download and compile the sources using travis? Compiling openjfx by hand is not a problem.

Comment: You have to use Gradle or Maven to build a compile task which you than can execute with the ci.